# Is it possible use camera inside from a xaml page?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I was wondering if it's possible open camera inside a small piece of screen from a custom xaml page. I'm not sure if WP7 API support stuff like that.

Version: Windows Phone 7.5 Mango

Comment: To avoid bickering in the answers below could you please specify what version of Windows Phone you are targetting? WP7.0 or WP7.5 "Mango"?

Comment: Should the exact tag used here matter? Would anyone want to target pre-Mango WP7? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215203/is-there-any-point-in-writing-pre-mango-7-0-windows-phone-7-applications

Comment: @ColinE :). I've retagged with both tags now the question text is explicit to keep everyone happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the camera as a live source of image data in your application. This is well documented in the [Code Samples for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28VS.92%29.aspx#BKMK_CameraAndPhotos) MSDN page. The demo code produces a simple application as follows:

[image]

You simply create a brush in XAML:

```
<VideoBrush x:Name="viewfinderBrush" />
```

And wire it up to your camera in code-behind:

```
 viewfinderBrush.SetSource(cam);
```

Comment: For that is for what version? All users on Mango now, so `windows-phone-7` tag means Mango by default. Also, you don't need to support 7.0 now, I guess

Comment: No Windows-Phone-7 means WP7 (original) Windows-Phone-7.1 and Windows-Phone-7.5 means Mango