# Pull-down-to-refresh listbox for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, pull-to-refresh

I'am wondering if is a way to implement the pull-down-to-refresh function of a listbox. I have followed [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasongin/archive/2011/04/13/pull-down-to-refresh-a-wp7-listbox-or-scrollviewer.aspx) to implement this function.
When I set the "ManipulationMode=Control", the listbox scroll performance is so poor that it is beyond my consideration.

I've also followed [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/30/windows-phone-mango-change-listbox-how-to-detect-compression-end-of-scroll-states.aspx)
to detect the top-compression state, but when I scroll top, the top-compression event fired. What I need is that the refresh-event will not fire until the user pulled down the listbox, holding for a white, or pulled down the top of the listbox. What's more, HorizontalCompression and VerticalCompression are only supported in 0s7.1.

I'm finding a way to implement this function for days. I'll appreciate if soneone could give me some advice. Thanks.

Comment: I've looked at both your links previously. Currently we use the end-of-scroll-states version and it works OK. Is supporting 7.0 really a big issue for you?

Comment: There is very little point in supporting WP7.0 these days ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215203/is-there-any-point-in-writing-pre-mango-7-0-windows-phone-7-applications

Comment: @Stuart thanks your reply. It's okay without supporting the 7.0,  but the VerticalCompression is too sensitive, when I scroll up to the top, the event fire, so it doesn't meet my need. Could you give more information on your method? thanks.

Comment: @ColinE :-) Because many windows phone devices in my region are with os7.0. Considering the compatibility, I want to support os7.0. But now it doesn't matter whether ths 7.0 is supported or not. I could use a refresh-button for os 7.0. So I would like to konw if there is a way to implement the pull-down-to-refresh effect. thanks.

Comment: @Stuart Hi,Stuart. I've keeping finding a way to implement the pull-down-to-refresh effect. Could you give me more tips on how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify after my comments...

I personally only support Mango now - but I understand and respect that other regions may need to continue supporting pre-Mango devices.

A Mango-only implementation of http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/30/windows-phone-mango-change-listbox-how-to-detect-compression-end-of-scroll-states.aspx is available within the Windows Phone projects in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/master/Sample%20-%20Tutorial/Tutorial - that's what I currently use.

I would very much like to get the other version (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasongin/archive/2011/04/13/pull-down-to-refresh-a-wp7-listbox-or-scrollviewer.aspx) ported and working - just need to find some time on that one...

Comment: Thanks Stuart, jasongin's post is helpful, but when I set the "ManipulationMode=Control", the listbox scroll performance is ugly. I've downloaded the project you shown me, I just find that the pull-down-refresh event is too sensitive, once scrolled top, it fired.

Comment: I don't understand that - when I pull down here then I get "Hold To Refresh" for a few seconds and the refresh itself only happens if you wait until "Release To Refresh" is shown?